# Register user in Symfony from an OAuth client

Tags: symfony, oauth

I'm building a REST api using Symfony2, FOSRest & FOSUser. I just implemented an OAuth v2 server with FOSOAuthServer but I have some question that don't find answers on Google:

- How to properly implement a user registration on my server from an OAuth client (ie an Android app)?
- Is there a standard url to call in this situation (like `/oauth/v2/auth_signup` or something more restful)?
- Should this register action be protected by oauth server? I think it shouldn't so this means a new firewall should be created to exclude oauth for this url, as this is the case for `/oauth/v2/auth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an OAuth context, your android APP will have a client_id, a client_secret, etc. You could use the `client_credentials` grant_type to get an access_token for this application.

`GET /oauth/v2/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=cId&client_secret=cSecret`.

This way you can now call, for instance, `POST /api/register` with a user in the body and register it. This call can be protected, but since you are logged in with the app, you make the call.

But you could create or own grant_type as well. For instace

`GET /oauth/v2/token?grant_type=custom&client_id=cId&client_secret=cSecret&username=u&password=p`

could check if a user exists with this username and register it if not.

Comment: Thanks for answer! :) So your first solution means that an access token is delivered but not linked yet to a user?


Edit: should not be a problem as client_crendentials is mean for this case, no?

Comment: Exactly. An access_token, with FOSOAuth, can be linked to a client or to a client and a user. The user can be null, it means that the access_token is only valid for the client. I think this is the purpose of client_credentials, yes. Provide an access to calls which don't need any logged in user.

Comment: isn't it dangerous to save the client id and secret in the client in the case of an app? they might be able to find it out and misuse it